# Detecting if screen can send touch events or not on Android?

Tags: android, screen, touch, detect

How do I detect whether or not the screen on an android device is a touchscreen?

I don't want to force the user to "press here" and see if I get an event, I'd like to detect it without asking the user to do anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `hasSystemFeature` method of the [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#hasSystemFeature%28java.lang.String%29) class to check for [FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN)